# Perfectly fixed background banner in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a banner on my page, that has this settings:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: url(...) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

But I fight with a combination of locked aspect ratio of background and responsive width and height of background.

When I have a locked aspect ratio of background (delete background size 100 100), it has blank spaces on every side, when window is resized above size of the image.

When I have `background-size: 100% 100%;`, then aspect ratio isn't locked.

When I have `background-size: 100%;`, then aspect ratio is locked, it has 100% width, but it has blank spaces on the top and bottom.

I'm asking you, if you could please teach me a combination of locked aspect ratio and have it without blank spaces. I created a **JSFiddle**, where I have every example: https://jsfiddle.net/30ycgsg0/

I'm thanksful for every response, have a nice day!

Comment: try now https://jsfiddle.net/30ycgsg0/

Comment: Have you tried background-size:cover; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-size:cover;`.

Because the aspect ratio of the element can be different than that of the image, and you don't wan't blank spaces, the image will sometimes be cut off.

Comment: This is it, I don't know, why I didn't tried cover. I'll mark it in 7 minutes delay :-) have a nice day and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
width : 100%;
height : auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove margin from body try to use this example

```
    body{
        margin: 0px;
    }
```